# get particular location start date on dynamically loaded textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, model-view-controller, datepicker

i have dynamic forms which has their respective start date added,

on each of these forms there is an option of adding laws start date and its regno,

i want the start date of each particular location on the laws start date

for example if i add 05/09/2017 on a location start date then this date should appear as 05/09/2017 on laws start date.

[image]

above is a screenshot of one form, i have multiple forms as these

can anyone help me with this.?

my code for the same is as this:

```
$(document).on('click','.date-picker2',function(e){
            var startdate = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('data-loc');
            startdate = $("#start_" + startdate).val();
            var splits = startdate.split("-");
            alert(splits);
            $(this).datepicker({
                todayBtn: "linked",
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                startDate: new Date(splits[2]+"-"+splits[1]+"-"+splits[0]),
                endDate: new Date(),
                onSelect:function(date){
                }
            }).datepicker("show");
        });
```

its problem is that its giving me start date of first location form only

not for the second and for third etc.

i want start date of particular location.

my form is this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/companymaster/updatelocationsdata', 'id'=>'location_update','method'=>'Post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => true)) !!}
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="company_id" id="company_id" value="{{$value->company_id}}">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="location_id" id="location_id" value="{{$value->id}}">
                                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                                                <h4 class="modal-title">View Location</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                    <div id="locationid_1">
                                                                        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4">CMS ID:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="cms_id" id="cms_id" class="form-control required " value="{{ $value->cms_id }}" aria-required="true" readonly="readonly">
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Country:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="country_name" id="country_name" class="form-control required" aria-required="true" value="{{ $value->country_name }}">
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4">State:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="state_name" class="form-control required " aria-required="true" value="{{ $value->state_name }}">
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Location:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                        <input type="text" name="location_name" id="location_name" class="form-control required location" aria-required="true" value="{{ $value->location_name }}" required>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Start Date:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="company_start_date" id="company_start_date" class="form-control required" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" aria-required="true" value="<?php if($value->company_start_date!=""){  echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value->company_start_date)); }?>">
                                                                                    </div> <!-- id="start_{{$value->id}}" -->
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>

                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4">End Date:</label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-7">

                                                                                        <?php
                                                                                        if($value->company_end_date!="")
                                                                                        { $end_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value->company_end_date)); }
                                                                                        if ($value->company_end_date =="0000-00-00")
                                                                                        {$end_date = null ;}

                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                         <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="company_end_date form-control date-picker required" onfocus="this.blur()" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled" value="{{$end_date}}" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" required>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:6px;">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4">IT Admin:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                            <?php
                                                                                                  $uservalue = DB::table('users')->where('company_id', $value->company_id)->where('role', 6)->where('location_id', $value->id)->whereNull('deleted_at')->first();
                                                                                            ?>
                                                                                                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="company_admin" id="company_admin" class="form-control required" aria-required="true" value="{{ $uservalue->first_name }} {{ $uservalue->last_name }} ({{ $uservalue->email }})">
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                                                 <label class="control-label col-md-4">Address:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                      <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                         <textarea name="company_location_address" class="form-control required" rows="3" aria-required="true" required>{{ $value->company_location_address }}</textarea>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                               </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Status:<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                                                        <select name="company_status" id="company_status" class="form-control" onchange="setstatus(this.value);">
                                                                                            <option value="1" <?php if($value->company_status=='1'){ echo "selected=selected"; }?>>Active</option>
                                                                                            <option value="0" <?php if($value->company_status=='0'){ echo "selected=selected"; }?>>Inactive</option>
                                                                                        </select>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="row">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Add Laws<span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span></label>
                                                                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                                                                        <a data-toggle="modal" id="" class="openmodal updateLaw" ><i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="font-size:24px;height:24px;" ></i></a>
                                                                                        <div class="updateloc">
                                                                                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$value->id}}" name="company_master_id">
                                                                                            <div class="sublaws_content" data-loc="{{$value->id}}"></div>
                                                                                            <div class="save" id="save" style="display:none; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success location_law_update" disabled="disabled">Update</button>
                                                                                                <a class="btn red" href="{{ URL::to('admin/companymaster/'.$company_master->id) }}">Cancel</a>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                        </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn green right submitlocation" id="submitlocation">Update</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn red" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you post html for all forms ?

Comment: what mean 1st, 2nd, 3rd? are you saying 1st form, 2nd form, 3rd form? how the second form and 3rd form is generated?  and how it work, pick from the model the date, and display on 1st, 2nd, and 3rd form?

Comment: there is no class date-picker2 in provided html. either you change class to date-picker in script or vise versa

Comment: my design for adding laws start date is on controller

Answer (score 0):

Do it on focusout or change event.It is now doing on click event on clicking it the value is not there in the field.

```
      $( ".date-picker2" ).change(function() {
   alert( "Do functions here" );
  });
```